# Lotus Notes - <Computed text> issue

Tags: field, lotus-notes

I have an editable field called `Number`. This field value changes to `""` every time a button is clicked.

So, I want to display its value using a < Computed Text > using as default value `Number`.

Is there any chance after the button was clicked, the < Computed Text > to display the 'old' value from the field `Number`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just need to store that old value somewhere before you clear it:

```
Field OldValue := Number;
```

And then retrieve it later:

```
Number := OldValue;
@Command([ViewRefreshFields]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've understood you need to use `Help Description` and `Field Hint` in field properties instead of your combination of computed text and event handlers.

Comment: Unfortunately those can not be computed by formula.

Comment: In described scenario user need to see some text in editable text and this text need to be disappeared when user starts typing inside the field, and that text need to be displayed somewhere after disappearing. It seems like @mfg-flay wants to have hint text with description how to fill that field. For that purpose Lotus has built-in functionality: `Help Description` and `Field Hint` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use computed for display field with formula:

```
@If( @IsDocBeingLoaded; Number; @ThisValue )
```

That way it will show value of `Number` field since opening.